# Verificar se a data selecionada é final de semana em javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um input no meu sistema que recebe uma data selecionada pelo usuário, gostaria de saber como posso fazer para verificar se essa data é um final de semana.

meu input funciona dessa maneira:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="data" name="data" placeholder="Data" required>  

$( function() {
  $( "#data" ).datepicker({showAnim: "slideDown", dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' , autoSize: true ,maxDate: "0" , minDate: "-2m", 

                                   dayNamesMin: [ "Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab" ],
                                   dayNamesShort: [ "Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab" ],
                                   monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez" ],
                                   monthNames: [ "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"]});

  $("#data").on("change",function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        Edit(selected);});  
} );
```

Comment: Se a intenção for de bloquear a seleção dos dias em finais de semana, o seu componente `datepicker` com certeza terá uma opção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que criar um objeto tipo Date se atentando com o timezone (GMT -0300) para o horário de Brasília, se for o caso.

```
var Minha_data = new Date('Fri May 17 2019 11:20:58 GMT-0300');
```

Ou de forma mais simplificada

```
var Minha_data = new Date(2019,4,17);
```

Os meses vão de 0-11 e por isso para o mês de Maio utilizamos o 4.

Depois você deve utilizar o método getDay() para pegar o dia da semana (0-6) para saber se é ou não final de semana. Onde 0 é Domingo e 6 é Sábado.

```
var e_fds = Minha_data.getDay() == 0 || Minha_data.getDay() == 6 ? true : false
```

Segue link para verificar o resultado https://jsfiddle.net/rmwbyzg5/

Comment: Funcionou desse jeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: @Romulo dependendo da importância desta informação, não esqueça de validar também do lado do servidor.